# Counting/bounding number of relatively prime pairs?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, combinatorial-number-theory

I'm wondering if anyone knows of results counting or bounding the number of relatively prime pairs in two subsets of positive integers.  In particular:

Given $A = \{a \in \mathbb{Z} | m_1 \leq a \leq m_2 \}$ and $B = \{b \in \mathbb{Z} | n_1 \leq b \leq n_2 \}$, is there a formula for or a bound on the size of the set $P = \{(a,b)|a \in A, b \in B,$ and $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime$\}$.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with the result that for fixed $m_1,n_1$, as $m_2,n_2$ tend to infinity the fraction of relatively prime pairs $(a,b)$ tends to $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$?

Comment: Yes, hardmath, I've got that result.  Thank you though.

Comment: If there is some information about the intervals $[m_1,m_2]$ and $[n_1,n_2]$ that you suspect will inform the counts/estimates, you should provide that.  Otherwise the count can be anything from no pairs to all pairs.

Comment: You can't mean "all pairs" in quite the way you have stated - as soon as you have two numbers in each interval you have a pair of even numbers. Constructing "no pair" examples of any size will also be tricky.

Comment: @MarkBennet: I'll assume your comment was directed to me.  Since the formulation explicitly allows either $m_1=m_2$ or $n_1=n_2$, it is possible to have "intervals" of a single integer.  With one single integer interval, there are many ways the other other interval can consist of no coprime integers or all coprime integers.

Comment: @hardmath Apologies , it was meant for you and got deleted and retyped. I agree about single integer intervals - my first draft had "in general" (acknowledging single integer intervals as a speial case) and I was interrupted for supper. A $2 \times 2$ no coprime pairs example is $(35,36),(14,15)$ - to construct larger examples requires picking out common prime factors (low primes can do lots of pairs, but larger primes only one). I'll see if I can construct a $3\times 3$ example.

Comment: @MarkBennet: No problem, I'm just drawing out the OP on the intended application as the "large interval" approximation (first Comment) seems already to be discounted.

Comment: Note that taking primes, we can look at $(2p,3qr,2s)(2q,3ps,2r)$ which have no coprime pairs, and then use modular arithmetic/ Chinese Remainder Theorem to create a set of triples having at least those prime factors. So with $p=11, q=5, r=13, s=7$ we get the triples $(5654, 5655, 5656)(14090, 14091, 14092)$. The method can be generalised to obtain rectangles as large as one wishes containing no coprime pairs.